# Eclipse Java Error: Syntax error on token "picture", ElidedSemicolonAndRightBrace expected

Tags: java

I am setting up a Java program in JFrame and JButton, and I want to open an image on the click of the button. and I get this error:

Syntax error on token "picture", ElidedSemicolonAndRightBrace expected

I've tried:

Adding semicolons, Adding curved brackets, Deleting semicolons, Deleting curved brackets.

```
private void initUI() {

    var button = new JButton("Quit");

    button.addActionListener((event) -> Image picture = ImageIO.read(new File("E:/picture.png")));

    createLayout(button);

    setTitle("Quit button");
    setSize(300, 200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: Enclose your lambda within curly braces

Comment: What is a lambda?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: He's referring to the body of the function being executed, changing it like this: `{Image picture = ImageIO.read(new File("E:/picture.png"));}`

Answer (score 0):

You have a lambda expression, and you will want to enclose it within curly braces to allow for multiple lines and required exception handling code:

```
button.addActionListener((event) -> {
    try {
        Image picture = ImageIO.read(new File("E:/picture.png"));
        // use picture here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Otherwise, there is no way to use the picture variable

Comment: I think he/she is using Java 9 or later, that's why there is a `var`.